# Android activity/fragment recreated when low memory

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, low-memory

I'm implementing an app that have multiple activities and fragment-based.
What I met is, if I start an activity, and transit between fragments, and now if I press home button back to home screen. Then I start using memory-consumed apps.
When I back to my app, I can know it has been recreated and fragment has been restored. But when I click back, the fragment back stack seems to be wrong, and custom animation between fragments also not affected anymore.

In my case, I don't really want system to recreate when back from low memory.
Is there a way to force app restart when low memory instead of recreating activity?

Answer (score 1):

As you probably know, the best solution would be to fix your activities so that they correctly handle the lifecycle events and save/restore state.  Then when your app goes into the background and returns to the foreground, the user sees the app as he/she last left it.  That is the best user experience and the way Android multitasking is intended to work.

If you are desperate for a workaround, consider using the [onTrimMemory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onTrimMemory(int)) method of Activity.  This method is called with an integer code that reports changes in the activity state such as when the activity is not longer visible, and where the app is in the list of recently used apps. For example, you could check for [TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks2.html#TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN) and call `finish()` to end the activity.

Again, that is not the preferred solution, just a quick fix.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue when the Activity gets created again the fragments misbehaved .What is the ideal solution in this case.How to maintain the fragments in low memory condition?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `onLowMemory()` if you're using API Level 13 or less:

> This is called when the overall system is running low on memory, and
>   actively running processes should trim their memory usage. While the
>   exact point at which this will be called is not defined, generally it
>   will happen when all background process have been killed. That is,
>   before reaching the point of killing processes hosting service and
>   foreground UI that we would like to avoid killing.
>
> You should implement this method to release any caches or other
>   unnecessary resources you may be holding on to. The system will
>   perform a garbage collection for you after returning from this method.
>
> Preferably, you should implement onTrimMemory(int) from
>   ComponentCallbacks2 to incrementally unload your resources based on
>   various levels of memory demands. That API is available for API level
>   14 and higher, so you should only use this onLowMemory() method as a
>   fallback for older versions, which can be treated the same as
>   onTrimMemory(int) with the TRIM_MEMORY_COMPLETE level.

For more information: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html